# how to java-script populate 2 select on selecting one?

Tags: javascript, php, select

Hi there i m new here in php so i need a help guys.
I have one input and 2 select option here i want ---- if input is empty than both select are also be empty if input have some value than first select options value should be 'open' and respectively second select value should be 'form distributed' like this, here the both select are working fine but not following by input field any help will be gratfull thank you

---

```
           <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) {
                    var Open = new Array('Form Distributed');
                    var Completed = new Array('Ready for billing', 'Completed');
                    var Pending = new Array('With CS', 'With O&M (Estimate)', 'With Delegate','With Executive Engineer','With Consumer (Payment)','With O&M (Connection)');
                    var Rejected = new Array('Rejected: By CS', 'Rejected: By O&M', 'Rejected: By Delegate','Rejected: By EE','Rejected: Demand Expired','Rejected: By O&M');

                    switch (ddl1.value) {
                        case 'Open':
                            document.getElementById(ddl2).options.length = 0;
                            for (i = 0; i < Open.length; i++) {
                                createOption(document.getElementById(ddl2), Open[i], Open[i]);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Completed':
                            document.getElementById(ddl2).options.length = 0; 
                        for (i = 0; i < Completed.length; i++) {
                            createOption(document.getElementById(ddl2), Completed[i], Completed[i]);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Pending':
                            document.getElementById(ddl2).options.length = 0;
                            for (i = 0; i < Pending.length; i++) {
                                createOption(document.getElementById(ddl2), Pending[i], Pending[i]);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Rejected':
                            document.getElementById(ddl2).options.length = 0;
                            for (i = 0; i < Rejected.length; i++) {
                                createOption(document.getElementById(ddl2), Rejected[i], Rejected[i]);
                            }
                            break;
                            default:
                                document.getElementById(ddl2).options.length = 0;
                            break;
                    }

                }

                function createOption(ddl, text, value) {
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = value;
                    opt.text = text;
                    ddl.options.add(opt);
                }

            </script>
            </head>
            <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker">
            <select id="ddl" onChange="configureDropDownLists(this,'ddl2')">
            <option value="0" ></option>
            <option value="Open">Open</option>
            <option value="Completed">Completed</option>
            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
            </select>

            <select id="ddl2">
            </select>



            </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: wat do u need exactly

Comment: if input is empty both select empty ,if input have some value than 1 select value should be 'open' and second select should be 'form disrtibuted'

Comment: Did you try  fro same on input also  <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" onChange="configureDropDownLists(this,'ddl')" >

Comment: i try everything as my knowledge of javascript i couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
changeInput();
$("#datepicker").change(function(){
    changeInput();
});
```

});

var optios = ['Open','Completed','Pending','Rejected'];
function changeInput(){

```
var input = $("#datepicker").val();

var ddl = document.getElementById("ddl");
ddl.options.length = 0;
document.getElementById("ddl2").options.length = 0;

if(input==""){


}else{

    $.each(optios,function(){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = this;
        opt.text = this;
        ddl.options.add(opt);
    });
    $("#ddl").val("Open");
    configureDropDownLists(ddl,'ddl2');
}
```

}

Comment: thanking you for help but sorry its not working . i hvae just put this code in my script tag but its not enough.

Comment: have u included jquery  src

Comment: i  dont know  how to do ?

Comment: but is shows option in select when input is empty, i just want when input is empty then they both select will be empty......

Comment: is select box itself empty or the selected value empty?

Comment: select box will be empty if input is empty (null) any select will not show any option to user.

Comment: thank you so much brother finely its working sorry it was my fault i miss it http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js link to mention in src of script